# ChatGPT API ISSUE

Tags: python, openai-api

Trying to use chatgpt API in order to code according API [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/chat-completions-api)...

```
def ask_chatgpt(question, model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.7, max_tokens=500):
    try:
        response = client.chat.completions.create(
            model=model,
            messages=[
                {"role": "system", "content": "you re an assistant."},
                {"role": "user", "content": question},
            ],
            temperature=temperature,
            max_tokens=max_tokens,
        )

        print(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])
        return
```

The issue is that this code is returning me:

> **'ChatCompletion' object is not subscriptable**

message instead the answer expected for.

Could someone help me in order to get the message value?

Just checking libs version

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-86:~$ pip show openai
Name: openai
Version: 1.12.0
Summary: The official Python library for the openai API
Home-page: None
Author: None
Author-email: OpenAI <support@openai.com>
License: None
Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: pydantic, typing-extensions, distro, tqdm, anyio, httpx, sniffio
Required-by:
```

Comment: This function doesn't even have the correct parameters according to documentation you linked to. So - first things first, read the documentation again, and follow their example.

Answer (score 0):

The API changed. See the [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742):

> Response objects are now pydantic models and no longer conform to the dictionary shape.

Use this instead:

```
completion.choices[0].message.content
```